# I unable to push my repo on GitHub pages even after renaming my html file to index.html, it only shows the README file.

Tags: html, css, github, web, web-hosting

Unable to host my repo on GitHub pages even after renaming my html file to index.html. It only shows the readme file after I click on the generated link.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your project directory make sure you do the following

To initiate a git repository

```
git init
```

Add your remote repostiory

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/test.git
```

Add all your changes

```
git add .
```

Commit changes

```
git commit -m "initial"
```

Push your commit to remote repository

```
git push -u origin main
```

After doing the following you should see all your files in your github repository